# Must the image url in a sitemap file begin with the same domain the file is stored on?

Tags: html, url, sitemap, images, xml-sitemap

I remember when making a sitemap, all URLs defined in between `<loc>` and `</loc>` must be part of the same domain as the domain the file is stored on. For example, I can use this line in my sitemap...

```
http://an.example.com/abc.html
```

...Only if the sitemap is stored on and publicly accessible from the folder mapped to the `an.example.com` domain.

But that entry above won't work if the sitemap is stored on a folder representing a different domain such as `y.example.com` or even `domain.com`.

My question is, should I use the above thinking when trying to index for Google images? For example, do image URLs defined in `<image:loc>` and `</image:loc>` have to contain the same domain as the location of the sitemap file the entries are contained in?

The reason why I ask is because I have two subdomains. Let's call them `t.example.com` and `i.example.com`. T is for text, and I is for images.

My site map for one page currently would look like something as follows:

```
<url>
<loc>http://t.example.com/page-one.html</loc>
<image:image>
<image:loc>http://i.example.com/image-one</image:loc>
<image:title>Some image</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
```

Am I wrong with using a different subdomain to reference the image? Assume the sitemap file is stored and accessed at `http://t.example.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: As far as I know, a sitemap can only contain references for the domain itself. For example, example.com cannot have a.example.com. A sitemap on a.example.com cannot have b.example.com. As far as I know, each would have to have their own sitemap.

Comment: ok I'll reconfigure my sitemaps to see if that helps

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok so I made the switch and due to sitemap writing rules, I included the required `<loc>` so now google says I submitted thousands of pages and thousands of images, but the links in `<image:loc>` are duplicates of `<loc>` just to conform to all specs. good luck me.

Comment: Ah NUTS! It may be time for a search.

Comment: Also you can make image sitemap on your sites, check this link : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can includes images from different domains (such as when using CDNs) if both domains are verified in your Search Console (formally Web-master tools) account, or you include an entry for the xml sitemap file in the other domains robots.txt.

[More info on Image sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en)

This is similar to including entries for URLs that reside on a different domain, which you can also do if both sites are verified in Search Console.

[Simplify multiple sitemap management](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en)